Checking if the correct power is on
I'm making a device with an stm32 nucleo-f303k8 board that I power with 12V directly through one of its pins. However it can also draw power from USB and it can happen than USB will be connected first, which is improper.
I'd like to know what would be the best way to check if the 12V power is on. Maybe an optocoupler?

Typicaly voltage divider will be sufficient.
